# Выбрать максимальные и минимальные значении

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
| ID  | tran_number | fiscal_date |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 1   | 1           | 2015-09-09  |
| 2   | 2           | 2015-09-01  |
| 12  | 10          | 2015-09-16  |
| 345 | 99          | 2015-09-16  |
| 457 | 107         | 2015-12-16  |
```

Здесь тип `tran_number` - `nvarchar(100)`.
Пробовал так:

```
    select 
'c №' +  Min(pe.tran_number + ' по № '+  Max(pe.tran_number) 
    from Cash.dbo.Payments pe
```

Max(pe.tran_number) не работает так как думаю тип nvarchar и выбирает как максимальную сумму 99

Я хочу получить такой результат:

```
| tran_number  |
| с №1 по № 107 |
```

Comment: Можно было не удалять предыдущий вопрос, а отредактировать его.

Comment: @Zhandos, вы хотите получить только максимальное и минимальное значения? Или же вы хотите  получить диапазон значений, от n минимального до n максимального? Почему бы вам на поле `tran_number` не назначить тип INT?

Comment: Хочу получить диапазон значении, Тип данных изменить не могу, здесь вместо макс 107 выбирает 99

Comment: @Zhandos, если вы хотите получить **диапазон значений**, то вам нужно задать для этого условие WHERE. Простой пример. Чтобы получить записи c идентификаторами от 1 до 10, запрос будет иметь следующий вид: `SELECT * FROM my_tab WHERE id>=1 AND id<=10`.

Comment: @ StasHappy, ok спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
select N'с №'   + cast(min(cast(pe.tran_number as int)) as nvarchar) +
       N' по №' + cast(max(cast(pe.tran_number as int)) as nvarchar)
```

Сперва выполняем приведение типа nvarchar к типу int, чтобы правильно работали функции min и max, а потом опять выполняем приведение к nvarchar, чтобы использовать конкатенацию строк.

Но я бы предложил получать запросом просто два числа:

```
select min(cast(pe.tran_number as int)), max(cast(pe.tran_number as int))
```

а строку желаемого вида формировать на клиенте.

И вообще похоже на ошибку проектирования, что числа хранятся в виде nvarchar.